# Custom label on ModelChoiceField form field

Tags: django, forms

I am using forms with the following:

```
class InvoiceModelForm ( forms.ModelForm ):

    u = forms.ModelChoiceField ( queryset = User.objects.all () )
```

But in the form field it is displaying the username.  I would like to change that to use the first and last names.

I do not want to change the

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

How can I change what values that are displayed in the form field?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See the last part of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

> The **str**() method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices. To provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance.

So, in your case you could do:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class NameChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f'{obj.first_name} {obj.last_name}'
```

and then,

```
class InvoiceModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

   u = NameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

Comment: Awesome, Django never stops surprising me!  Cheers.

Comment: superb ... like it